# How to have fixed height for a horizontal scrolling webpage differently to devices?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a horizontally scrolling website, the difficulty i am facing is to fix my page's height to the device's. Furthermore, if i fix the height's value in the css then it becomes hard coded for that particular screen size, so whenever i open the page on a differently sized monitor the hard coded value creates trouble. I have used a very basic css till now, here it is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style media="screen">
  #body {
    width: 4000px;
    height: auto;
    max-height:100vh;
  }
</style>
<title></title>
</head>
<body id=body>
--\\CONTENT GOES HERE \\--
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `max-height: 100vh` should indeed be constraining your `#body` to never go beyond that height. You'll obviously need to make sure none of the content exceeds that though. You may wish to add `overflow-y: hidden`. Other than that, it's nuclear what problem you're having -- it would help to specify the problem you're having with your current approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make body have 100% of the browser height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height)

Comment: Or Possible duplicate of [Horizontal scrolling page, mobile browsers adding vertical height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35641448/horizontal-scrolling-page-mobile-browsers-adding-vertical-height).

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you are looking for. You can add an `overflow-y`property as well just to be sure y scrolling is disabled. Just make sure the rest of your content is responsive so that it can resize with the view height.

```
   #body { 
        width: 4000px;
        height: auto;
        max-height: 100vh;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
```